# Security Software Edit anti-virus & Edit Host IDS API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

After i purchased Anti-virus or Host IDS, what is right api for Edit anti-virus & Edit Host IDS (like Security Software List of Softlayer control) 
i'm now implement in java but if there are other languages samples, let me know

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rslqr.png)

Answer (score 0):

To `Edit anti-virus`, please see (Rest example):

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Software_Component_AntivirusSpyware/9510197/updateAntivirusSpywarePolicy

Method: POST

Json payload:

{
  "parameters": [
    4,
    true
  ]
}
```

**References:**

[SoftLayer_Software_Component_AntivirusSpyware::updateAntivirusSpywarePolicy](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Software_Component_AntivirusSpyware/updateAntivirusSpywarePolicy)

To edit `Host IDS Policy`, please see the following request:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Software_Component_HostIps/[Host_IDS_id]/updateHipsPolicies

Method: POST

Json Payload:

{
  "parameters": [
    "On_10",                # IPS Mode
    "Maximum Protection",   # IPS Protection
    "McAfee Default",       # Firewall Mode
    "No_Rules",             # Firewall RuleSet
    "",                     # newApplicationMode, this option cannot be set in Control Portal (N/A)
    "",                     # newApplicationRuleset, this option cannot be set in Control Portal (N/A)
    "__EPO_ENFORCE_YES__"   # Enforcement Policy
  ]
}
```

To get values to set in the above request, please execute:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Software_Component_HostIps/[Host_IDS_id]/getObject?objectMask=enforcementPolicyNames;ipsModePolicyNames;ipsProtectionPolicyNames;firewallModePolicyNames;firewallRuleSetPolicyNames
Method: GET
```

The response would be something like this:

```
{
  "hardwareId": 588888,
  "id": 9700000,
  "manufacturerLicenseInstance": "0CC47A581D3888",
  "epoVersion": "4.5",
  "enforcementPolicyNames": [
    {
      "name": "__EPO_ENFORCE_YES__"
    },
    {
      "name": "__EPO_ENFORCE_NO__"
    }
  ],
  "firewallModePolicyNames": [
    {
      "name": "McAfee Default"
    },
    {
      "name": "My Default"
    },
    {
      "name": "Off [McAfee Default]"
    },
    {
      "name": "On"
    },
    {
      "name": "Adaptive"
    },
    {
      "name": "Learn"
    },
    {
      "name": "Custom_FWONSpecial_DONOTUSE"
    }
  ],
  "firewallRuleSetPolicyNames": [
    {
      "name": "McAfee Default"
    },
    {
      "name": "Typical Corporate Environment"
    },
    {
      "name": "SLDefault"
    },
    {
      "name": "No_Rules"
    },
    {
      "name": "My Default"
    }
  ],
  "ipsModePolicyNames": [
    {
      "name": "McAfee Default"
    },
    {
      "name": "On_120"
    },
    {
      "name": "On [McAfee Default]"
    },
    {
      "name": "Adaptive_10"
    },
    {
      "name": "Adaptive_120"
    },
    {
      "name": "Adaptive_UR"
    },
    {
      "name": "On_10"
    },
    {
      "name": "On_UR"
    },
    {
      "name": "Off"
    }
  ],
  "ipsProtectionPolicyNames": [
    {
      "name": "Basic Protection [McAfee Default]"
    },
    {
      "name": "Enhanced Protection"
    },
    {
      "name": "Maximum Protection"
    },
    {
      "name": "Prepare for Enhanced Protection"
    },
    {
      "name": "Prepare for Maximum Protection"
    },
    {
      "name": "Warning"
    }
  ]
}
```

**References:**
[SoftLayer_Software_Component_HostIps::updateHipsPolicies](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Software_Component_HostIps/updateHipsPolicies)